# Input saves as you type to collection - how to update UI?

Tags: meteor

First - I am having a hard time formulating this question, so please bear with me, and ask for clarification and I'll try to provide as much as I can. I am just starting to learn meteor, so be patient please.

I have several inputs that save immediately as people type on them. (with a slight 300 ms delay to not overload database).

Basically, on "keyup" it goes and saves. All that works fine. However, I'd like to add a visual indicator (say a green checkmark, or a tiny "saved") when the database actually stores what they typed.

Graphically:

[___________________]

[Typed something_____] (**saved**)

[___________________]

I am not sure how to go about this, but it's something common, that plenty of you have already done. If I didn't care about the database feedback, I'd just use JQuery, target a class beside the input and make the checkmark or word visible after a keyup, or add it to the DOM. Fairly straight forward.The only when I am sure it has been stored in Mongodb part confuses me.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.
Thank you

Addendum with code:

```
Template.dibs.events({

'keyup input.name': _.throttle(function(event) {
  Dibs.update(this._id, {$set: {name: event.target.value}});
  $(':focus + .glyphicon-ok').css('opacity',1);
}, 300),
```

Can you explain where/how you would add the code? (For spinner, or the words).
Coming from JQuery I did something that I know is not the right way. This is in the client portion (I know just demo code, and it's not secure) but I wanted to know the best way leveraging meteor to do it. I already have checkmarks stating it was saved in the page, but they are all hidden, this code just makes them visible on keyup for the field.

I read through the article, and didn't quite see how I'd go about doing the intermediate step (spinner or the like) then the finalized checkmark after code is saved. I've also being going through the new 1.0 tutorial (which is great) but I'm still missing the visual indicators. It's great that meteor updates the UI if it fails in the server to reflect that it didn't save, since I am assuming success, I don't think that tapping into the Meteor.Error makes sense. Should there not be a Meteor.Success or equivalent?

Again, I apologize for the long message, I'm trying to wrap my head around this, because the technology looks very promising

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Meteor! Meteor was in fact designed (among other things) to handle just this type of situation, via a mechanism called Latency Compensation. You can read more about it at [Meteor.methods](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods).

> Calling a method on the server requires a round-trip over the network. It would be really frustrating if users had to wait a whole second to see their comment show up due to this delay. That's why Meteor has a feature called *method stubs*. If you define a method on the client with the same name as a server method, Meteor will run it to attempt to predict the outcome of the server method. When the code on the server actually finishes, the prediction generated on the client will be replaced with the actual outcome of the server method.

You can use Latency Compensation by defining a Meteor method to save the input text to the database, with a client stub that displays a spinner instead of "saved", and "saved" when its callback is called successfully.

Alternatively, you can call the [`update` method](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update) on the collection directly, and add a callback on the client, which will be called with `(error, numberOfDocsUpdated)` after the server method returns.

Read more on [when to use Meteor methods and when to use client-side operations](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I'll read up on this during the weekend. Method stubs seem like what I'd want. I'll mark the answer as accepted then.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan has said, the Latency Comp takes care of needing to do this. Another way of doing this is in a template event. You can set a session variable on keyup with the contents of the text field and in the helper, set a flag that will render the checkmark when the session variable and current user input matches.